# read from excel file to datatable asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I got this code to read from a excel file after uploading

```
 public static DataTable getDataTableFromExcel(string path)
    {
        using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                pck.Load(stream);
            }
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();





            bool hasHeader = true; // adjust it accordingly( i've mentioned that this is a simple approach)
            foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
            {
                tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
            }






            var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
            for (var rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
            {
              var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
               var row = tbl.NewRow();
              foreach (var cell in wsRow)
               {
                 row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
               }
             tbl.Rows.Add(row);
              }
            return tbl;
           }

    }

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploader/") + filename);
            err.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
            DataTable dt =  getDataTableFromExcel(Server.MapPath("~/Uploader/") + filename);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            err.Text = dt.Rows[1].ToString();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            err.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

but i cannot understand it well ... if you could give me a little description about it ?
and how to read specific column
I need to read just the first and third and fifth column not all ... how to do that ?

Comment: You need to explain what you think the code is supposed to do, and specifically what about it you don't understand. Otherwise your question is kind of broad.

Comment: i need this code to upload an excel file then read this excel and put it in datatable to store it in database ... but not all the column need to stored just 1 - 3 -5 column ... and i don't understand where the modification should be ... i cannot understand how this code read and write